# Chrome opacity transition z-index issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, google-chrome

I'm working on an angular app and I'm having an issue when adding a '.active' class to a nav item.

Here is a stackblitz link that demonstrates the issue:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjqyft?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Basically, when I click a box, it scales but part of the next box is showing, almost like the active box is transparent.  My active class has a z-index of 1 and an opacity of 1.

On Firefox, this doesn't seem to be an issue.  Also, I've done something similar using the same technique before (but without any frameworks).  This [link](https://xmtrinidad.github.io/aplus902/) will show you an example from that project.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it's a Chrome issue.  I appreciate any feedback.

EDIT:  Just checked on Edge and the same issue is there.  So far it seems like Firefox is the only browser where this issue doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `position:relative` to either the `.section a` or `.active`

Such as:

```
.section a {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: all .5s;
  position:relative;
}
```

The reason the clicked element seems as if it has opacity <1 is that the next element is actually "above" it, while having `opacity: 0.5;`. By "above it" I mean that the next element is further down the DOM tree, hence having a higher stacking order than the previous (currently the clicked one).